# Query regarding Regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

The data along with the [regex pattern I'm using is linked here](https://regex101.com/r/oEDsXu/1):

```
(?m)(?<=Note:)(\w+|\s+)*$
```

The sample text is:

```
Date:21
Month:03
Year:2017
Amount:50
Category:Test
Account:Testimg
Note:Tested

Date:21
Month:03
Year:2017
Amount:48
Category:Great
Account:Good
Note:Better
```

As you can imagine, I want all the text after the word "Note:" including the spaces and right up to the end of the line. I'm getting the results I need, but I'm not sure if this is a proper solution.

Is this the right way of going about it? Could it be made simpler?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not `/^Note:(.+)$/m`? Do those lines always start with `Note:`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it doesn't select all Notes... select only first note

Comment: In PHP, with `preg_match_all`, it will. Look at https://regex101.com/r/y0r9Bj/1

Comment: Yes, they always starts with Note:

Comment: See [a PHP online demo](https://ideone.com/VCypV4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your lines start with `Note:` and you need to use `^` anchor before it. You may use *capturing* as I suggested in my first comment:

```
preg_match_all('/^Note:(.+)/m', $s, $matches)
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/y0r9Bj/1).

Here, `^Note:(.+)` will assert the position at the start of the line, then `Note:` will get matched, and then any 1+ chars other than line break chars will get captured into Group 1, you will just need to access it using the right index.

Alternatively, use `\K` to drop the `Note:`:

```
preg_match_all('/^Note:\K.+/m', $s, $matches)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y0r9Bj/2)

Here, `^Note:\K.+` will also match the `Note:` at the start of the line, and then the text will be dropped due to `\K` match reset operator, and then 1+ chars other than line break chars will get consumed and placed into the match buffer.

Note the `$` anchor is not even necessary here, since `.+` will only match greedily up to the end of line on its own.

Comment: The second solution is *fantastic*! Thank you for the help 

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this to just `/Note:(.*)$/gm`, I've updated your [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/oEDsXu/2). But other than that yes you're going about it the right way.